# Cannot find namespace 'google'

Tags: google-maps, ionic2

After upgrading from Ionic2 beta to RC3,

I ran:

`npm install --save @types/google-maps`

which added the following to my `package.json`:

`"@types/google-maps": "^3.2.0",`

My `index.html` has:

```
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

My code contains:

```
declare var google: any;
...
public map: google.maps.Map = null;
```

But I get the following error when I run `ionic serve`:

> `Cannot find namespace 'google'.`

In my IDE (VSC), if I click on `google`, it takes me to `node_modules\@types\googlemaps\index.d.ts` which seems to have the correct definition.

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: maybe you forgot `npm install google-maps --save`?

Comment: @SurajRao. I have just tried: `npm install google-maps --save`. It seems to have added `"google-maps": "^3.2.1"` to my `package.json`, which I guess I need anyway, thank you. But I still get the same error when I try run `ionic serve`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually Ionic native already has google maps. You can check it out [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/google-maps/)

The actual plugin is [here](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps).

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-googlemaps --variable API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID="YOUR_ANDROID_API_KEY_IS_HERE" --variable API_KEY_FOR_IOS="YOUR_IOS_API_KEY_IS_HERE"
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks like what I am missing. I will give it a try and mark this as the answer if it works.

Comment: Thank you. That works. It is how it should be done with the newer version of Ionic 2.  https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/google-maps/

Comment: @Richard, have you tried to test your app on device (ionic run android) with this code?  in my case is not shown the map on device. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Future readers may not have the same luck that you did in resolving the issue. It's clear from the backslashes in your path that you're on Windows. In that case, this excerpt from [my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47491760/871990) may be of interest:

> You're using ionic, and there's a platform difference under some
>   circumstances (not sure who is responsible, ionic or typescript) where
>   the same tsconfig.json file will work on macos (and maybe linux), but
>   not in windows without explicitly adding a typeRoots entry to the
>   compilerOptions of your tsconfig.json, like this:

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ... other stuff
    "typeRoots": [ 'node_modules/@types' ]
  }
  // ... other stuff
}
```