# Cannot find namespace 'google' in ionic 3 app

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

can anyone help me with this error im getting in my ionic 3 application after my attempt to use google variable in my project,

> npm install --save @types/google-maps

which added the following to my package.json:

> "@types/google-maps": "^3.2.0",

i also did declare declare var google;

and did `typings install dt~google.maps --global`

then i seen this soultion and tried it but that did not work either (notice i generated an ios key and android key)
tried this
[Cannot find namespace 'google'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41359496/cannot-find-namespace-google)

> ionic cordova plugin add
>   https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps#multiple_maps
>   --variable API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID="YOUR_ANDROID_API_KEY_IS_HERE" --variable API_KEY_FOR_IOS="YOUR_IOS_API_KEY_IS_HERE" $ npm install --save @ionic-native/google-maps

gist for my map.ts thats shooting this error:

https://gist.github.com/abdulfatah-ah1407281/25bc95352d0b1ba8e02b7d1e55cc7779

Error when i run ionic serve:

```
Cannot find namespace 'google'.
C:/Users/pkhon/Desktop/k/ItBroken/src/components/map/map.ts
private map: google.maps.Map;
public isMapIdle:boolean;
```

Answer (score 6):

You didn't mention it, but I'm guessing you're on Windows. You're using ionic, and there's a platform difference under some circumstances (not sure who is responsible, ionic or typescript) where the same `tsconfig.json` file will work on macos (and maybe linux), but not in windows without explicitly adding a `typeRoots` entry to the `compilerOptions` of your `tsconfig.json`, like this:

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ... other stuff
    "typeRoots": [ 'node_modules/@types' ]
  }
  // ... other stuff
}
```